# How to Change theme of Recaptcha to darkmode

Tags: android, recaptcha

I am using SafetyNet verifyWithRecaptcha and the look and feel of it is for a light theme like below:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to change the theme of Recaptcha to black in android?